# Setting up collisions in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am in the process of setting up collisions in swift, when I came across this error that I can't seem to get rid of. I can change a line of code around to fix that error, but when I do that, more errors occur.

```
 let collisionHitBox = CGRect(x: 201, y: 139, width: 398, height: 212)

 barCollisions.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: collisionHitBox)

    let ballCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    let barCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

   ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ballCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ballCategory | barCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory | barCategory

     barCollisions.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = barCategory
    barCollisions.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true






    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
       let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
       // This is where I get an error saying "Initialization of immutable value was never used, consider replacing it for removing it"    

        let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballCategory) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == barCategory)
        {
          let contactPoint = contact.contactPoint
            let contact_y = contactPoint.y
            let target_y = secondNode.position.y
            let margin = secondNode.frame.size.height/2 - 25
            if (contact_y > (target_y - margin)) && contact_y < (target_y + margin) {

                print("GameOver")


            }
        }
```

Comment: I think this message cannot be more clear. Once you fixed it, give us your new error. I'll guess an error with ballCategory and barCategory that are not declared. But anyway xcode should give you a meaningful message ;) It seems like basic debugging, not sure if this post can be useful to other...

Comment: When I switch (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == barCategory)     to    (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == barCollisions), the original error disappears but instead I get an error saying : "Cannot convert value SKNode! to argument type UInt32"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just saying that you set firstNode but you are not using it, so you can remove this line

Comment: I know but I feel like with the code that I have, the firstNode should be in use. When I switch (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == barCategory) to (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == barCollisions), the original error disappears but instead I get an error saying that it can't covert an SKNode to UInt32.

Comment: Those error are not related one another. And you can't compare SKNode (barCollisions)  to UInt32 (categoryBitMask)